# Lit-translate shows code or key instead of translation

Tags: javascript, typescript, translate

I am trying to use lit-translate to translate my "Elmish" typescript website into different languages. I use webpack and dotnet.

Inside my index.ts I register the translate config:

```
registerTranslateConfig({
    lookup: (key, config) => config.strings != null ? config.strings[key] : key,
    empty: key => key,
    loader: lang => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve({"title": "Der Titel"});
          })}   
    });

use("en");
```

(The loader is hardcoded because getting the localization file also didn't work, but that's not important for now).

Inside html I use `get("title")`or `translate("title")` to get the translation.
Instead of the translation, I either read [title] or
`(part) => { partCache.set(part, cb); updatePart(part, cb); }`

If I assign the result of `translate()` to a variable, I get the following result inside the Object:

```
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.r (<anonymous>:1:83)
    at Module../src/index.ts (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:9800:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:12476:33)
    at http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:13494:11
    at http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:13497:12
```

I already tried disabling webpack strict mode.

The full class looks like the following:

```
export class App extends Application<Model, Message, {}> {
  @property({type: Boolean})
  hasLoadedStrings = false;

    init(): [Model, Cmd] {
    const initModel: Model = {
      openPage: [{title: "Home"}, home]
    }

    return [initModel, Cmd.none]
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.hasLoadedStrings = false;
  }

  shouldUpdate (changedProperties: Map<string | number | symbol, unknown>) {
    return this.hasLoadedStrings && super.shouldUpdate(changedProperties);
  }

  async connectedCallback () {
    super.connectedCallback();
 
    await use("en");
    this.hasLoadedStrings = true;
  }

}

customElements.define('my-element', App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing my own little translation library.
The lit-translate package contains errors if you use it as suggested in the documentation so feel free to use my solution:

translate.ts:

```
const de_config = 
{
  "Category": {
    "Home": "Start",
  },
  "Home": {
    "Welcome back,": "Willkommen zurück,"
};

export function translate(key: string) {

    const keyParts = key.split(".");
    const keyCategory = keyParts.shift();
    const keyWord = keyParts.join('.');

    let translationIndexes = typedKeys(de_config);

    for(let translationIndex of translationIndexes)
    {
      if(translationIndex == keyCategory) {
        let translationKeys = typedKeys(de_config[translationIndex]);
        
        for(let translationKey of translationKeys) {
            if(translationKey == keyWord) {
              return de_config[translationIndex][translationKey];         
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return key;  
  }

function typedKeys<T>(o: T): (keyof T)[] {
    return Object.keys(o) as (keyof T)[];
  }
```

Access translations with:

```
import { translate } from './translate';
translate("Category.Home");
```

One could also store translation object in a different file, write a function to change language dynamically, etc...